# Why must apt GPG-keys be world-readable?

Tags: apt

When using the "Signed-by" option for apt repo entries, apt throws an error if the key is not world-readable.

Example:

```
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/hashicorp.gpg] https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com jammy main

sudo chmod 660 /etc/apt/keyrings/hashicorp.gpg
sudo apt-get update  


https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com jammy InRelease  
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY DA418C88A3219F7B  

sudo chmod 664 /etc/apt/keyrings/hashicorp.gpg  
sudo apt-get update  
Hit:10 https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com jammy InRelease
```

Why is this?

Comment: Hello. Since Ubuntu 22.04 does not exist yet any question related to it is off topic at this time Sorry.

Comment: It's reproducable on Focal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They don't have to be world readable, but they do have to be readable by the user apt runs as. Apt, even when run as root, typically drops privileges for actions that don't need them, by switching to the `_apt` user. For example:

```
# getent passwd _apt
_apt:x:100:65534::/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
# strace -f apt update |& grep si_uid
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=708, si_uid=0, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
[pid   709] --- SIGINT {si_signo=SIGINT, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=707, si_uid=0} ---
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=709, si_uid=0, si_status=100, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
[pid   712] --- SIGINT {si_signo=SIGINT, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=707, si_uid=0} ---
[pid   707] --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_KILLED, si_pid=712, si_uid=0, si_status=SIGINT, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
[pid   715] --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=716, si_uid=100, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
[pid   717] --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=718, si_uid=100, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
[pid   715] --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=717, si_uid=100, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
```

Note the UID of many of the child processes is 100, that of the `_apt` user.

That said, there's no advantage to be gained from making the keys readable only by root.

Comment: To clarify on the last point, the (public) keys used by APT are publicly available information that can be trivially obtained based on a list of which repositories are configured for the system, which in turn can be rather easily determined simply based on what’s installed.